# str_replace text with image

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a chat box and would like to replace things such as ' :D ' with an icon.

```
$chatText = str_replace(":D","<img src='images/icons/smileys/smile-big.png' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />",$chatText);
```

Above is the code I'm using. On the chat, instead of replacing text with emotions, it literally replaces the ":D" with the html code:

```
<img src='images/icons/smileys/smile-big.png' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />
```

I have made a few attempts at changes (that I've researched) such as:

```
$chatText = str_replace(":D", "< img src=\"/images/icons/smileys/smile-big.png\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" alt=\"Big Smile\" />",$chatText);
```

I've had no luck there. My question is how can I get this to work, so users are able to have emotions. At the very top of my code I also have `$chatText = htmlspecialchars($chatText, ENT_QUOTES);`

Comment: What is the question? [Your code seems working fine](http://codepad.org/FOL5IfmR)

Comment: You are escaping the content too late. You replace the text correctly, but then you escape it with `htmlspecialchars`, which is correct to avoid XSS, but in this case also escapes your valid html.

Comment: I would suggest using single quotes around the replacement string you you don't have to escape the double quotes, but I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: The problem is that instead of replacing :D with an emotion, it replaces it with the html for it: `<img src='images/icons/smileys/smile-big.png' width='20' height='20' alt='Big Smile' />`

Comment: I guess your chat box is a textarea? Within a textarea any string is taken as it is. So your html code gets displayed as code instead interpreted as an image. You have to fix it with some javascript (may be use any wysiwyg editor) or you display the text not inside of a textarea.

Comment: only the user input is a text area, but all they will do is enter something like :beer: and when its on the chat area, like on a IM. The emotion will show

Comment: Show us full code so we can help you.

Comment: The full code is here: http://codepad.org/shSlb42r

Comment: **update** i've removed `$chatText = htmlspecialchars($chatText, ENT_QUOTES);` as it was replacing grammar (such as apostrophes) with its HTML Number (&#039;)

Comment: Why don't you just parse it as soon as the content is loaded? I think autolinking it afterward than saving it to the sql like wouldn't give much more workload to the server?

Comment: If it is not a text area, what is the HTML portion where the $chatText is printed on ?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of possible problems — not 100% clear from your code:

#### Possibility #1: You're not setting the text in a TEXTAREA or something

If you're just setting the text for a textarea, then it doesn't support nested HTML, and you're not going to be able to do the smilies this way. Things like gmail and facebook, that DO support these, have basically re-implemented rendering of the content.

To correctly set the text, you want to use the `innerHTML` property of some particular `div` element to get the HTML correctly set.

In JQuery I'd probably write:

```
$('chat_text').html($('chat_text').html() + fixed_up_smilie_text);
```

#### Possibility #2: You're using `htmlspecialchars`

If you escape the text using `htmlspecialchars` before putting it in the HTML, then you'll see what you're seeing above. The fix is easy:  Don't ^_^.