# preg_replace for emoticons (php)

Tags: php, preg-replace

[REVISED FROM OLD QUESTION- NOW USING DIFFERENT WAY FORWARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161084/str-replace-text-with-image)

I am building a chatbox and would like to use emoticons. So when one sends " :) " it is replaced by and image of it, unfortunately with my code this doesn't happen. I have done quite a bit of experimentation too, I've learned `str_replace` will achive my project goose eggs, and I have decied to use `preg_replace`

```
<?php

$message = $chatText;

$emoticons = array(
"/\:\)/");


$replacements = array(
"<img src='images/icons/smileys/smile.png' width='20' height='20' alt='Smile' />");


$chatText = preg_replace($emoticons,$replacements,$message);


?>
```

Instead of replacing the ":)" with the smiley face, it just inserts the text `<img src='images/icons/smileys/smile.png' width='20' height='20' alt='Smile' />`

Comment: why not using http://php.net/bbcode

Comment: Are you using `htmlspecialchars()` or similar function later in your code?

Comment: Why not just use `str_replace()` instead of a regex?  You can pass in arrays of searches and replacements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [str_replace text with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161084/str-replace-text-with-image)

Comment: htmlspecialchars()  is not used within the chat.class no

Comment: thank you @jack yes, it is KINDA like a duplicate except that is my OLD question which uses `str_replace` and not `preg_replace`

Comment: @Rsmithy make the changes to your old question instead of creating a new question that's functionally identical.

Comment: my old question never received an answer- this new one has. Thanks @kolink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with your regex, rather an issue with how you are displaying the data. At some point you are using something like `htmlspecialchars` to prevent chatters from injecting HTML into your chat window. Unfortunately this results in smileys being escaped too.

Your code for replacing smileys should come somewhere *after* escaping the original text.

Comment: There's nothing  that's stripping html chars as far as I can see. I did use `htmlspecialchars` but removed it, but I'm still having the issue

Comment: How are you adding the text to the document? Are you maybe using `createTextNode` in JavaScript?

Comment: okay within the DB.class there is `public static function esc($str){
  return self::$instance->MySQLi->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($str));` but removing it causes problems with sending messgaes

Comment: I said the smileys should be anywhere after the escaping. So replace the smileys when you get the message back from the server (before sending it to the browser) instead of before saving them in the database. In other words, save `":)"` as it is to the database, then when you get it out you can replace it.

Comment: `<?php

function dosmilies($chatText) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM smilies";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($chatText = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$chatText = str_replace($chatText['chatText'], "<img src='{$chatText['image']}'>", $chatText);
}
return $chatText;
}

?>`  that's what I have but it doesn't do anything :) just sends as :) and isn't replaced

Comment: Erm... That's because you're overwriting the `$chatText` variable, using it as the name of an argument and your iterator in the while loop. Use different var names.

Comment: still nothing :/ `<?php

function dosmilies($str) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM smilies";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$str = str_replace($chat, "<img src='{$chat['image']}'>", $str);
}
return $str;
}

?>`

Comment: You forgot to specify an index at `str_replace($chat,` - it's trying to replace an array with a string. I'm questioning whether you should be programming in the first place.

Comment: I'm new to php replace functions

Comment: I always mess up the simple stuff *self shame*